# SQL My Sub Query is Loading Forever

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, subquery

Okay so basically I am trying to run a simple query with a subquery on phpmyadmin using mysql and it won't stop loading after I run it. The query is:

```
SELECT t.tagValue FROM tags t WHERE t.tagID IN (SELECT ua.tagID FROM user_taggedArtists ua WHERE ua.userID = 2);
```

I have ran the individual queries on their own without combining them together and they seem to do what I want, but when I mix them into a subquery form phpmyadmin just loads forever, like I am getting an infinite loop or something.

tags table looks like that:

╔═══════╦═════════════╗
║     tagID    ║          tagValue         ║
╠═══════╬═════════════╣
║               1 ║ metal                       ║
║               2 ║ alternative               ║
║               3 ║ pop                          ║
╚═══════╩═════════════╝
etc.

user_taggedArtists table looks like this:

╔════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ userID         ║ artistID             ║ tagID        ║ day      ║ month       ║ year          ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ 2                  ║ 52                    ║ 1               ║ 1         ║ 4               ║ 2009         ║
║ 2                  ║ 52                    ║ 1               ║ 1         ║ 4               ║ 2009         ║
║ 2                  ║ 52                    ║ 1               ║ 1         ║ 4               ║ 2009         ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╩═══════╝
ect.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you radarbob and Mike Nakis! You guys rule! Both of those queries seemed to work! Still not sure why my subquery method wasn't working but regardless at least I am able to pull the data that I want. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say 'zatly, but "IN", generally, is slow. Try a JOIN and WHERE. I'm going to pretend we can join on tagID. You should have indexes on the join column(s). If not anything you do will perform poorly.

```
SELECT t.tagValue 
FROM tags t 
INNER JOIN user_taggedArtists ua ON
    t.tagID = ua.tagID
WHERE  ua.userID = 2
```